# Git keeps requiring password but none of my password/tokens/passphrase works

Tags: git, github, ssh, passwords

On a linux ubuntu server, I have set up git/github already with ssh key-pair authorization. It was working before last week. However, suddenly when I use `git pull` or `git push`, or simply `ssh -T git@github.com`, a strange password request showed up

```
>git push
git@github.com's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

```
ssh -T git@github.com
git@github.com's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I tried the *passphrase* used for ssh key-pair, and also tried re-generating ssh key-pair several times and updating them on github. I also tried typing the *account password* used to log into github.com. I even tried the *personal token* generated from github.But none of these works.

What could happen to the server that causes the strange issue? Anyone knows how to resolve it?

Thank you!

Comment: To debug `ssh` issues : try `ssh -v git@github.com`

Answer (score 0):

> a strange password request showed up

That means the SSH keys proposed by your local SSH client do not match the public key registered in your GitHub account.

You can see what is used with `ssh -Tv git@github.com` (as [LeGEC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86072/legec) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72371462/git-keeps-requiring-password-but-none-of-my-password-tokens-passphrase-works#comment127852907_72371462)).

Try, for testing, to generate one without passphrase:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -f ~/.ssh/github
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="/usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/me/.ssh/github"
git clone git@github.com:me/myRepo
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use ssh protocol repository url, it does not ask for your username and password/token. We've encountered similar issues lately, which are due to ssh config.

If you've configured ssh keys correctly and it still doesn't work, try this.

Edit `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and add these lines

```
Host *
       HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
       PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Comment: I get the following error: Bad configuration option: pubkeyacceptedalgorithms

Comment: @ffonz Are you using git-bash? If so, upgrade it to the latest version and use the integrated ssh.